# Trait Requires `call-by-value`, but Implementation Tries with `call-by-name`

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> trait F {
     |   def foo(x: Int): Int
     | }
defined trait F
```

I tried to create an implementation of `F`, however I made `foo`'s argument `call-by-name` rather than `call-by-value`.

```
scala> class FImpl extends F {
     |   override def foo(x: => Int): Int = 55
     | }
<console>:12: error: class FImpl needs to be abstract, since method foo in trait F of type (x: Int)Int is not defined
(Note that Int does not match => Int)
       class FImpl extends F {
             ^
<console>:13: error: method foo overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class FImpl contain the following, non final members named foo:
def foo(x: Int): Int
         override def foo(x: => Int): Int = 55
                      ^
```

The compiler explains why my attempt failed.

Per my example, is it possible to define a `F#foo` function that takes either a `call-by-name` or `call-by-value` parameter?

Comment: Why don't you just define `foo(x: => Int): Int` in your trait `F`?

Comment: This isn't an answer since you're taking `F` as a given, but `cats.Eval` is designed precisely to provide this kind of abstraction over evaluation strategy.

Comment: You can make the trait method by-name and if an implementation wants to work as if it was by value, it should just evaluate the argument(s) at the beginning.